# Vue 3 Typescript watcher not responding after passing prop through two components

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I've got three components in my vue 3 app (using typescript and the composition api)

I'm reading a string value in the first component passing it throught a modal (2nd component) to a 3rd one.
Now the property gets to the 2nd component without an issue and I can read it there use it in a ref or whatever.
When passing the prop further to the 3rd component the watcher for that prop is not reacting to changes.

When I print the prop via another watcher I can see that its value is changing as I intended but the watcher does not react at all

Watcher code looks like this and I'm just passing props through the other components normally but this watcher is not reacting to changes.

```
const { myprop } = toRefs(props);
watch(myprop, (val: string) => {
      output.value = val;
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor your watcher like the follow example.

```
watch(() => props.myprop, (val: string) => {
    output.value = val;
}, { immediate: true });
```

I think your watcher doesnt recognize the changes because myprops hold a reference from the parent component.
Im not quit sure, i need more context to understand.